# Cron tab to run every two minutes after X minute of the hour

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, cron

I have a crontab that I'd like to run at 10 past the hour, 12, 14, 16, etc.

Currently I'm using this:

```
10-59/2 * * * * STAGE=production
```

I know that every other minute is `*/2`, but is this the correct format for every two minutes "starting at 10 past the hour" ?

Comment: The short answer is yes. Cron expands `*/2` in the minutes column as such: the `*` turns into a list of every number from 0 to 59 and then the `/2` takes that list and removes every 2nd member. So the list you're left with (but don't actually see because this happens behind the scenes) looks something like `0,2,4,6,8,10...56,58`. `10-59/2` follows the exact same process, just with a smaller list than you'd get had you expanded `*` instead

Answer (score 0):

The expression you have listed means to run every two minutes between the minutes of 10 and 59.  So I think the answer to your question is simply, "yes."

You can play around with cron expressions here and get explanations/expected run times if you're ever unsure.  https://crontab.guru